# Flutter contact_picker crashes on android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I cant seem to figure this out.

I have added read contacts permission to my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

I am also using permission_handler

```
    bool status = await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted;

    if (status) {
     Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
     //get contact info
    }
```

the contacts screen shows but as soon as I select a contact, the app crashes.

here's the logs right after I tap a contact.

```
D/AndroidRuntime(17070): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(17070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17070): Process: com.medlog.app, PID: 17070
E/AndroidRuntime(17070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2015, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/2426 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.medlog.app/com.medlog.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.app.Activity.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5202)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5243)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.app.Activity.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at vn.sendo.flutter.contactpicker.ContactPickerPlugin.onActivityResult(ContactPickerPlugin.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:634)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:367)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:546)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:594)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8303)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5195)
E/AndroidRuntime(17070):    ... 11 more
I/Process (17070): Sending signal. PID: 17070 SIG: 9
```

Here's my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-PH)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

By the way, this works perfectly on iOS.

Comment: When you're asking a question regarding a package, it's helpful if you provide a link to that package in your question so we can know exactly what package you are talking about. (There are several contact-picking packages out there.)

Comment: That being said, it appears you are referring to [native_contact_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/native_contact_picker). This error seems to be stemming from a bug in the native Android code, so you probably want to post this issue on the package's [repository issue page](https://gitlab.com/hungldm/native_contact_picker/-/issues).

Comment: Now _that_ being said, it looks like someone did post an issue [regarding this same bug](https://gitlab.com/hungldm/native_contact_picker/-/issues/1) seven months ago. The cause of the issue is a change in flutter's plugin loading that was made in version 12 which broke how the plugin stores a reference to the global `Activity`. Seeing as how the author never replied to that issue and you are experiencing the same issue now, it's safe to assume that the plugin is effectively abandoned. If you want to use it, you will have to backdate your version of flutter to something prior to 12.0.

Comment: (Of course, you could also always fork the repository, make the necessary fix, and just use that for your project.)

Comment: Thank you @Abion47. Appreciate you taking time in looking it up. I posted it past midnight after I being so frustrated about it. It seems that I need to look for other ways in getting contact information.

Comment: If your only goal is to retrieve contact information, there are plenty of other plugins capable of doing so that are much better maintained. This plugin only differentiated itself by also having a means of displaying the contact list, which may or may not be a good thing depending on if you have your own method of displaying the contact list in mind (or if that's even what you wanted it for).